# asp.net mvc 5 handle unknow controller name from url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

In Asp.net Mvc 5 How we can redirect another page if controller name is invalid in url like `http://localhost:51056/free`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983131/redirect-to-home-index-when-page-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting to a controller name that doesn't exist will always return an HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.

Probably the best way would be to set up a redirection rule on your server that redirects `/free` to some other path that does exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can set configuration in **web.config** like

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.shtml" />
</customErrors>
```

or You can do this in **Global.asax**

```
if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404) {
  // handle this
}
```

Comment: In theory you could have this redirect to a a different controller than the one requested and that would handle the 404 in a way that would allow the user to continue working on your site. So if `/free` is a deprecated link that people are still somehow using (from an outdated share somewhere else maybe) then you could do this to get them to the new url. Only drawback would be that it'd work that way for **EVERY** 404...